# Migrate CRA to Vite causes "Cannot access 'store' before initialization" using Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, vite

I've googled for days, and I just can't seem to solve the bug. So here I go.
I know it's all about circular dependencies, but it doesn't seem like I can just rewrite it.

First I'm initializing the store in its own file

```
/redux/store
const store = configureStore({ ... })
export default store;
```

Then in an API file, I use a util function (coming later) that is used in multiple places around the app. Here is an example

```
/api/configApi
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react';
import { getConfig } from 'utils/getConfig';

const token = getConfig(env.key);
export const configApi = createApi({ token, ... })
```

Then I am using `store` again, and sadly before it is initialized

```
/utils/getConfig
import store from 'redux/store'

export function getConfig(key) {
  const config = store.getState()... // <-- Cannot access store before initialization
}
```

And the app itself

```
/src/index.tsx
... imports ...

const app = (
  <StrictMode>
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <App />
    </ReduxProvider>
  </StrictMode>

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

All this about that it is a circular dependency makes sense to me.
But I can't just make an export from another file. I have to use `store` in `getConfig`

How can this be solved?

It works smoothly using `react-scripts` but blocks the whole procedure migrating to Vite.

Is it somehow possible to bundle `/src/redux` so this part works as it was Webpack? No?